# What are the common workarounds for multi-line comments in Perl?

Tags: perl, comments

**[This RFC](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/rfc/5.html)** mentions

> Unlike many programming languages Perl does not currently implement true multiline comments. This, and **the workarounds that are in common use** can be problematic. This could be solved by adding a new syntax to allow for comments to span more than one line, like the variation on here-documentation cited below.

What are the *common* workarounds?

Two techniques I found [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=166955) are

```
if (0) {
  <comment>
}
```

and

```
=pod
<comment>
=cut
```

Are these safe to use? Are there others that work better?

Comment: Why is putting a `#` at the start of each line considered onerous in the first place? Lots of editors can do that with macros (or equivalent) easily enough…

Comment: Don't put too much stock in Perl 6 RFCs. Larry rejected most of them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The downside of the "if" solution is that the commented out code still has to be compiled (and therefore still has to be syntax checked).

The downside of your pod solution is that your comments will appear in any documentation generated from the pod.

I use a version of the pod solution that doesn't have that problem. Pod supports `=begin format` ... `=end format` paragraphs that are handled by specific formatters. I just invent a "comment" format that isn't handled by any of the formatters I use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "This line is executed\n";

=begin comment

print "This line isn't\n";

=end comment

=cut

print "This line is\n";
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to keep the first (unsatisfactory) version in the answer? I don't think it adds anything to the solution. Could you just edit your answer and remove it, so that people see the correct solution right away? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The Perl documentation tells you how to do it in [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html). It's plenty safe, and since we can do it with Pod, we don't need additional syntax to do it:

---

How can I comment out a large block of perl code?

You can use embedded POD to discard it.  Enclose the blocks you want to
comment out in POD markers.  The `=begin` directive marks a section for
a specific formatter.  Use the "comment" format, which no formatter
should claim to understand (by policy).  Mark the end of the block with
`=end`.

```
   # program is here

   =begin comment

   all of this stuff

   here will be ignored
   by everyone

   =end comment

   =cut

   # program continues
```

The pod directives cannot go just anywhere.  You must put a pod
directive where the parser is expecting a new statement, not just in
the middle of an expression or some other arbitrary grammar production.

See [perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Although it's non-standard, I just use

```
=ignore 

sub blah { ... }
my $commented_out_var = 3.14;

=cut
```

It works just as well, and reminds me that it is not POD.

- Aside: It is an interesting thing that POD gives us a flexible framework for including various regions that should not regarded as code, specifying what that region means. Clearly we "comment things out" because comments work this way. Yet, it is clear from the term that comments are meant to be words, not instructions; documentation not alterations.

Answer (score 7):

An editor with a "Comment Region" function.

For example, Komodo Edit. I'm pretty sure Eclipse and JEdit do it as well, but I don't have them handy to check.

The feature usually inserts a "Comment this line" symbol at the start of every line in the selected region. It has the benefit of not conflicting with existing comments (which is a risk if you wrap an area containing a multi-line comment in most languages)

Comment: for example? I use `vim` which [supports only C/C++/Java comments](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Comment/UnComment_visually_selected_text).

Comment: Vim with the perl-support plugin uses the =pod/=cut method.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556

Comment: https://github.com/petdance/vim-perl or simply [upgrade to Vim 7.3](http://perlbuzz.com/2010/08/vim-73-supports-perl-6.html).

Comment: @Lazer: it's quite easy to edit a number of lines at once in vim, even easier in gvim. Just pop into visual hilighting mode, select a range, insert text, and <bam>.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite multi-line comment device is `__END__`.

```
print "Hello world\n";

__END__

The script has ended. Perl does not treat this part of the file as code.

I can put whatever I want down here. Very handy.
```

Comment: @FM: How do you use it in Perl?

Comment: @Lazer: `__END__` is documented in [perldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) -- you might want to consider spending a bit more time on the perldoc site and familiarizing yourself with its documents (as well as picking up a Learning Perl book).

Answer (score 4):

This works too:

```
q^
   This is another way to 
   add multi-line comments
   to your code
^ if 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the

```
=begin comment

multi-paragraph comments here

=end comment

=cut
```

form in other answers, you can also do this:

```
=for comment
this is a single pod paragraph comment do
not put extra blank lines after =for.  the
comment ends after the first blank line and
regular pod continues until =cut

Hello! C<Yay!>

=cut
```

the comment paragraph will not appear in the pod output, but the Hello "Yay!" will.

Answer (score 1):

One special use-case is commenting out several lines of code. But if you use a version control system, you can just *delete* unwanted code rather than commenting it out, and if you ever need it back, just fetch the old revision.

Answer (score 1):

Something like works too:

```
q{
my comment
};
```

THis is an expression I guess evaluated while running Perl.

Comment: I like that simple approach but I am getting following warning: `Useless use of a constant in void context`.

Comment: Are you afraid of warnings?

Answer (score 1):

This even simpler construct worked for me

```
=comment

It was hard in the Moonta Mines that year
For the miners, down in the pit,
It wasn’t a place for a weak man, but
The Cornish Miners had grit,
They burrowed deeper with every day
Extracting the copper ore,
And the skimps grew high in the heaps that piled
Not far from the Moonta shore.

=cut
```

Answer (score 0):

I use that way and works for me

```
=head

"your code to comment
monkey
banana"

=cut
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another helpful way!

---

```
=begin GHOSTCODE

whatever you want to uncomment

=end GHOSTCODE

=cut
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a Perl syntactical way to do it, but in most editors (like Notepad++) you can highlight code you want to be commented out, and then press CTRL+K. To remove the comments you can highlight them and press CTRL+Shift+K.

Comment: Select desired lines and then press `CTRL+Q`. This will toggle comments _on_ and _off_.