# How do I enter a multi-line comment in Perl?

Tags: perl, comments, multiline, perl-data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the common workarounds for multi-line comments in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608957)

How do I add a multi-line comment to Perl source code?

Comment: simply do
 
    =head
    ##your code to comment
    =cut

Answer (score 167, accepted):

POD is the official way to do multi line comments in Perl. See:

- **[Multi-line comments in perl
  code](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=560985)** and
- **[Better ways to make multi-line comments in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=100344)** for more
  detail.
- [How can I comment out a large block of Perl code?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7#How-can-I-comment-out-a-large-block-of-Perl-code?)

> The quick-and-dirty way to comment out more than one line of Perl is
> to surround those lines with Pod directives. You have to put these
> directives at the beginning of the line and somewhere where Perl
> expects a new statement (so not in the middle of statements like the #
> comments). You end the comment with `=cut`, ending the Pod section:

```
=pod

my $object = NotGonnaHappen->new();

ignored_sub();

$wont_be_assigned = 37;

=cut
```

> The quick-and-dirty method only works well when you don't plan to
> leave the commented code in the source. If a Pod parser comes along,
> your multiline comment is going to show up in the Pod translation. A
> better way hides it from Pod parsers as well.
>
> The `=begin` directive can mark a section for a particular purpose. If
> the Pod parser doesn't want to handle it, it just ignores it. Label
> the comments with `comment`. End the comment using `=end` with the
> same label. You still need the `=cut` to go back to Perl code from the
> Pod comment:

```
=begin comment

my $object = NotGonnaHappen->new();

ignored_sub();

$wont_be_assigned = 37;

=end comment

=cut
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to start the comment with =POD, you can use any thing to start Multi-line comment ( say =xyz etc ) But yes end must always be with =cut not even =CUT

Answer (score 32):

I found it. Perl has multi-line comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

=for comment

Example of multiline comment.

Example of multiline comment.

=cut

print "Multi Line Comment Example \n";
```

Comment: Between `=for comment` and `=cut`, from the second paragraph, it will be shown in *perldoc*.  So only the first paragraph would be fully commented from both codes and *perldoc*.  If this should be avoided, use `=begin comment` ...multi-lines/paragraph comments... `=end comment (*new-line*) =cut`.