# What inspired Ruby's =begin .. =end comment block syntax?

Tags: ruby, history

I know that a lot of Ruby was inspired by Perl (e.g. STDIN as a global constant) or Unix shell (e.g. the `<<END` heredoc syntax). But I don't know where the block comment syntax comes from. The syntax:

```
=begin
This is a comment line
it explains that the next line of code displays 
a welcome message
=end
```

Where does this come from? My knowledge of Perl is sketchy. Is it Perl?

Comment: I like the question but its probably for the ruby-core mailing list.

Comment: To those voting to close: I don't see how this will "solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" and not "involve facts, references, or specific expertise". It would seem to be answerable in a straightforward manner.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

yes, this is Perl

Perl uses

```
=begin
This is a comment line
it explains that the next line of code displays 
a welcome message
=cut
```

have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Comments

Comment: It's part of the [POD syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) used to extract inline documentation from  Perl code, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3828297/239657