# Comments are getting executed when I run the Perl Script

Tags: perl

Some of my perl statements are executed even after commenting. I tried all the delimiter `#`, `/*..*/`, `//`
Does anyone face the same issue or can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post examples

Comment: please post examples showing what you did, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, in sufficient detail that someone else can take your example and observe the result you did.

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information to know what your problem is, but assuming you're having trouble with multi-line comments, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828205/how-do-i-enter-a-multi-line-comment-in-perl).

Comment: `/* .. */` and `//` are not comments in Perl. The first one might be interpreted as a regex, the second is the defined-or operator.

Comment: Show a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). The problem you have is because of your source code, it cannot be solved without knowing your source code. The best you can get is a guess, and trying to guess is annoying at best.

Comment: At the command prompt type "`perldoc perlintro`".  Fifteen minutes later you will have the answer to this, and many other "getting started with Perl" type questions.

Comment: Thanks everyone.i got the mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be "How do I create a comment in Perl?"

[perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) says thusly:

> Text from a "#" character until the end of the line is a comment, and is ignored. Exceptions include "#" inside a string or regular expression.

For example,

```
 print "apple\n";  # Keeps the doctor away.
```

Keep in mind that comments can only be used where whitespace is expected. For example, the following does not contain any comments since the `#` is part of the string literal.

```
 print "apple      # Keeps the doctor away.
 orange
 ";
```