# Syntax highlight for perl in Emacs is broken, is there a fix?

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

I'm a perl programmer and a new emacs user. I'm under Windows, using cperl-mode for editing perl. Emacs version is 24.2.1. Here's a screenshot with some sample code:

[image]
<sub>(source: [breqwas.net](http://breqwas.net/dropbox/perlsyn_emacs.png))</sub>

1. Obvious bug: it highlights arrays, hashes and non-quoted literal values in ( a => "b" ) style lists *inside comments*
2. One more bug: it highligts the first word in a regular expression as an array because of non-default quote symbol
3. Not a bug, but looks weird: it highlights arrays and hashes any time when they are used (even in comments, huh), but scalars are highlighted only when declared
4. Not a bug, but looks weird: same story with functions: highlighted when declared, not when called
5. Not a bug, but looks weird: why do "print", "say" and "system" have different colors?

I could keep going, but I hope that explains the word "broken" pretty well.

Then I learned the magic C-u C-x = key combination, which shows, among other stuff, the text properties for the text under the cursor, hoping to make a better coloring scheme of my own. At this point it started making even less sense.

"print" has *cperl-nonoverridable-face*. "die" has *font-lock-keyword-face*. Meanwhile, both are functions and can be (and often are) overrided. "system" has *font-lock-type-face*. Why? Function declarations have *font-lock-function-name-face* - that's OK, but so do the arguments of "use". Why? Function calls and scalars don't have face property at all and can't be highlighted. Why? Etc, Etc. Again, I could keep going.

Is there a way to fix all that? Is there some config where I can remap lexical units to some other font-faces, or some other way to make the syntax highlight less crazy?

To avoid the "perl is unparsible" talk, here's a screenshot of the editor I'm migrating from, with the very same code: http://breqwas.net/dropbox/perlsyn_pn.png. Looks much more reasonable.

---

**Upd:** By now (3 weeks after asking this question here) I did not find a cure. All perl programmers who use emacs I know just ignore these problems. No better perl highlighters for emacs seem to exist. Reading cperl-mode docs provides some explanations (the choice of faces for various elements seems less crazy now), but does not provide any answers. I wrote an email to cperl-mode maintainer with these questions and some more digging I did, but got no reply.

Yep, you got that right: seems like emacs community was not able to make a good perl syntax highligting in 25 years that perl is around. That's a sad story.

Comment: I am just living with that. Consider setting `cperl-highlight-variables-indiscriminately` to `t`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try `perl-mode` instead of `cperl-mode`.  If you find missing features in it we might be able to port them from `cperl-mode` without too much trouble.  `perl-mode`'s highlighting is less gaudy than `cperl-mode`'s but it does fix some of the problems you point out.

As for "highlighted when declared, not when called" this is because Emacs usually highlights in this way.  I find there is zero benefit to highlighting variable and function uses.  I kept the highlighting of variable uses in `perl-mode` mostly because it was there before and I didn't want to deal with disgruntled users.  Also, in the case of Perl, it's probably easier to highlight variable declarations and uses identically as does `perl-mode` whereas `cperl-mode` has to do extra work to distinguish those two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax highlighting snafu to watch out for with Emacs cperl-mode relates to POD comments used to comment out blocks of code. Here's a screenshot to demo:

[image: cperl-mode syntax highlighting bug demo]

It's VERY easy to miss commented out code that uses POD directives without blank line padding as in my 'not recommended' example above. It just does not hit your eye as a comment when viewing it in Emacs, especially if the commented block is large and spans multiple screen pages so that the '=cut' lines aren't even in view.

It's worth noting that **vim**'s Perl mode correctly highlights the POD without requiring blank line padding per the POD spec, though I would caution vim users to avoid relying on that feature and use blank line padding and '=begin comment ...=end comment' directives as shown above and [as recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608957/what-are-the-common-workarounds-for-multi-line-comments-in-perl).

It would be nice if Perl had a simpler multi-line comment syntax a la '/* ... */' rather than the POD mechanism that is subject to abuse. Perhaps we'll get this in Perl 6 some day?

Another way do multi-line comments in Emacs (for any language) is via the 'string-rectangle' built-in: C-x r t then type '# '. To uncomment a block, either do it manually or write a simple macro.